# How do I retrieve an outbound Twilio Client calls' SID after it connects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

Hello working hard on a Twilio app for my company but I'm still kid of new. I have the following function making an outbound connect request to my Twilio App. Thing is my company wants to be able to log call duration at the end of each call and for that I need to retrieve the child call SID. I've heard from some that this can only be achieved from the back end. I'm just using the standard Twilio Function right now that's including with the Their Twilio client quickstart. Can anyone tell me what I have to add to return the Child SID?

```
//Here's the Front End function
export function twilioCall(num, device) {
    return dispatch => {
        device.on('connect', () => {
            let status = device.status();
            if(status === 'busy') {
                dispatch({type:CALL_STATUS, payload: true}) 
            }
          });

        device.on('disconnect', () => {
            let status = device.status();
            if(status === 'ready') {
                dispatch({type:CALL_STATUS, payload: false})
            }
          });

        const params = {
            To: num
          };
        device.connect(params)
    };
};

//And the Back End Function
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    if(event.To) {
      // Wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
      // if is a valid phone number
      const attr = isAValidPhoneNumber(event.To) ? 'number' : 'client';

      const dial = twiml.dial({
        callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
      });
      dial[attr]({}, event.To);
    } else {
      twiml.say('Thanks for calling!');
    }

     callback(null, twiml);
};

/**
* Checks if the given value is valid as phone number
* @param {Number|String} number
* @return {Boolean}
*/
function isAValidPhoneNumber(number) {
  return /^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/.test(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the REST Calls resource, and filter on Parent CallSID (the CallSID of your Twilio Client), as documented at the URL below.:

```
client.calls.list({
    parentCallSid: parentCallSid
},
    calls => console.log(calls);
);
```

Calls

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call